# Using WPF Resources in newly loaded components

Tags: c#, wpf, vb.net

suppose that I have a code like this:

```
<Grid>
    <Grid.Resources>
        <SolidColorBrush x:Key="myBrush" Color="Black" />
    </Grid.Resources>

    <ContentControl Content="{Binding View}" />
</Grid>
```

Later in run-time I will put a `Page` Control in that `ContentControl`. Now I want to use `myBrush` resource in the page which i will load.

For example my `Page` is like this:

```
<Frame>
    <Page>
        <TextBlock Foreground="...WHAT..." Text="Im in myBrush Color!"/>
    </Page>
</Frame>
```

**What Should I use in *...Waht...* to reference to `myBrush` Resource??**

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the solution!

It's enough to merge caller plugin resources with calling plugin resources:

```
Loaded = PluginManager.CreateInstance(plugin.LoadPath, plugin.ClassName)
Loaded.Resources.MergedDictionaries.Add(Me.Resources)
```

Answer (score 0):

Use a `StaticResource`:

```
<Frame>
    <Page>
        <TextBlock Foreground="{StaticResource myBrush}" Text="Im in myBrush Color!"/>
    </Page>
</Frame>
```

See [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms750950%28v=vs.110%29.aspx)

Comment: Thank you for giving time,
But what about if my `TextBox` placed in a `DataTemplate`?

Comment: `StaticResource` Can't be used since I have no `myBrush` in plugin control!